# How to get applicationID and server in Parse setup?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push

I am setting up a parse server in android but I don't know what value to be put in applicationID and server field while initialising parse object. How do I get those values? I am using windows, my code is as below:

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .applicationId("com.example.anshuman.parse_1")
            .server("http://18.220.188.73:4040")
            .build()
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.back4app.com/docs/overview/parse-create-new-app, did you try with back4app you have all explanations there